# Simulated Annealing, How to normalize the probability distribution

Tags: c++, machine-learning

I am working an a solver for an arbitrary non-linear higher order equation solver.  I want to find the minimum. The issue here I am having is how do I normalize the probability distribution function.  I don't want to have to integrate over all variables (plus I might as well find the minimum by brute force if I just do that.)  Here is my code.  How can I normalize the exponential term.

```
template<typename Real, int N, typename Funct>
    Vector<Real, N> simulated_anneling_solver(Funct f, const Vector<Real, N>& lower_bound, const Vector<Real, N>& upper_bound, int t_start)
    {
        static int called_count = 0;
        std::default_random_engine eng;
        eng.seed(time(0) * ++called_count);

        Vector<Real, N> x;
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            x[i] = (upper_bound[i] + lower_bound[i]) * (Real)0.5;
        Real v = f(x);
        for(int t = t_start; t > 0; t--)
        {
            Vector<Real, N> next_x;
            Real cooled_percent = (Real)t / t_start;
            for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                Real dimw = upper_bound[i] - lower_bound[i];
                do
                {
                    next_x[i] = std::normal_distribution<Real>(x[i], dimw * cooled_percent)(eng);
                }
                while(next_x[i] < lower_bound[i] || next_x[i] > upper_bound[i]);
            }

            Real next_v = f(next_x);

            if(next_v <= v || expx((next_v - v) / t) > std::uniform_real_distribution<float>(0.0f, 1.0f)(eng))
            {
                v = next_v;
                x = next_x;
            }
        }

        return x;
    }

}
```

PS.  I tried changing `expx((next_v - v) / t) > std::uniform_real_distribution<float>(0.0f, 1.0f)(eng)` to 
`(next_v - v) / v < cooled_percent` which seems to give some good results.  Now I know that I am just taking the percent error of the function and comparing it to how much it has cooled.  Therefore everything is normalized and bounded between zero and one. You will need a lower percent error as the system cools.  I guess now though it isn't really simulated annealing.

Answer (score 0):

In simulated annealing there is no need for normalization because the if clause in your program should be like:

```
if(next_v < v || 
     expx((v-next_v) / t) > std::uniform_real_distribution<float>(0.0f, 1.0f)(eng))
{
    v = next_v;
    x = next_x;
}
```

where expx will always yield value in (0,1].